# Ambiguity Error after changing Resource File

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET application that is available in two languages: English by default and Portuguese as second option.

Everything was working good, look this first image:

[image: explorer before changing resource file]

Then when I try to add or remove a string resource, visual studio starts to give me ambiguity errors when compiling, as those:

> The namespace 'VolunteerGames.Web.Translations' already contains a
>   definition for 'Translation'

and

> Ambiguity between
>   'VolunteerGames.Web.Translations.Translation.ResourceManager' and
>   'VolunteerGames.Web.Translations.Translation.ResourceManager'

I noticed that after changing the resource in designer (Translation.resx) a new file named **Translation1.Designer.cs** was created. It created another class called **Translation**. If I delete this new file I can compile, but the new strings I just created are not found when I try to use on my controller.

[image]

I can't understand what's going on. I've been working for months in this project and it was all good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because Visual Studio started to create the file **Translation1.Designer.cs**, and that new file conflicted with **Translation.Designer.cs**, and when I tried to delete it I got erros, then I deleted **Translation.Designer.cs** so everything is working now again.

[image]

Comment: Any idea why Visual studio create Translation1.Designer.cs?

Answer (score 0):

For late-comer who encountered with the [same problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/danielfe/2008/04/27/settings1-designer-cs-bug-multiple-settings-files/)

It looks like the project was created in ResX Schema older version (v1.3) but reopen(and save) in ResX schema v2.0, since the Schemea is auto created, the VS will do so because schema standard is different is not adaptable. We can have two files with completely same name in one directory, it attached a number with its original name